# How to calculate (or prove rigorously) that the Taylor series expansion of sine function converges to 0 when you plug in pi?

Tags: trigonometry

There was a similar question asked before but I find the answers to it quite lacking in precision and completeness.

Comment: What is $\pi$ for you if not the first positive zero of $\sin$?

Comment: It would be nice if you give a reference to "a similar question" and point out where you see the lack in precision and completeness.

Answer (score 1):

From your question I infer that you want to consider the series 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and then show that $f(\pi) = 0$.

First, the series converges absolutely for all $x$ due to the ratio test, so that $f(\pi)$ is well-defined. To show $f(\pi) = \sin(\pi)$, we can use Taylor's theorem with remainder. Recall that the remainder $R_n(x)$ is the difference between $\sin(x)$ and the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial $T_n(x)$, so that $R_n(x) = \sin(x) - T_n(x)$. Taylor's remainder theorem (in this case) says that for each $x$ there exists a point $c$ in the interval $[-|x|, |x|]$ with $$R_n(x) = \frac{\sin^{n+1}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$ Substituting $x = \pi$ and taking limits, 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} |\sin(\pi) -T_n(x)| = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|\sin^{n+1}(c)|}{(n+1)!}\pi^{n+1} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\pi^{n+1} = 0.$$

On the other hand,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\sin(\pi) -T_n(x)| = |\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(\pi) - \lim_{n\to \infty} T_n(x)| = |\sin(\pi) - f(x)|, $$

so that $\sin(\pi) = f(\pi)$, as desired. Of course, this is completely general and also proves that $$\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Comment: What definition of $\sin(x)$ do you use?

Comment: Which one is used here?